# Android and Java Socket don't have the same behavior

Tags: java, android, sockets

I'm using **Java** to implement some socket programs.

I found that both of Android and Java have `java.net.Socket`, but the source code are not the same, so that they have different behavior.

I have a server(maybe PC or Android), and the server has multiple network interface(E.g. Ethernet, Wireless, USB or Bluetooth). The client will try to connect all the server network interface at the same time(one connection one thread). Until the client finds an available connection, they will communicate via the connection. In this way, I expect that the connection speed will not too low.

But when the client is trying to connect to server, it may encounter a repeat-connect situation in Android device(Android SDK). If the program encounter the repeat-connect situation, the previous connection will be reset or be replaced(I'm not sure) by the latter connection. At the same time, when reading or writing the previous connection, it will throw java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer). In the other hand, when reading or writing the latter connection, it is normal, but the connection speed is not very fast.

**This problem seems to not be happened on PC but happened on Android when the client is trying to connect to server.**

How can I solve it?

**EDIT**

The client code as below:

```
private Socket socket;
private IP ip;
private IP[] IPs;
private boolean closing;
private int socketTriedCount;
...
socketTriedCount = 0;
for (final IP ipObj : IPs) {
    if (closing) {
        break;
    }
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                if (socket == null) {
                    final Socket s = new Socket();
                    s.connect(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName(ipObj.getIP()), ipObj.getPort()), timeout);
                    synchronized (Client.this) {
                        if (socket != null) {
                            //Should not be happened
                            //s.close();
                            socketTriedCount++;
                        } else {
                            ip = ipObj;
                            socket = s;
                            socketTriedCount++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (final Exception ioE) {
                socketTriedCount++;
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Comment: Any code? Mb you are implement it not correct.

Comment: Client code is pasted

Comment: Bluetooth? You need a different socket for it isn't it? `private IP[] IPs;` ? Whats in there? I see no `multiple network interface` in your code.

Comment: Multiple network interface is used in the server side. Bluetooth can also share network.

Comment: IP is a data object to store IP and port.

Comment: My server may have multiple network interface, and have multiple IPs.
For instance, Ethernet ip is 192.168.0.1, Wireless ip is 192.168.1.1, USB ip is 192.168.2.2, Bluetooth ip is 192.168.2.3

The client will know these IPs from server

Comment: The port in IP object is the server TCP accepting port

Comment: My program is correct on PC, but is not correct on Android, very weird.

Comment: Define 'repeat-connect situation'.